# Паскаль. Табличное шифрование с ключевым словом

Tags: pascal, шифрование

Моя программа должна шифровать и расшифровать текст с помощью ключевого слова. У нее есть две части, часть шифровки и дешифровки. С шифровкой все понятно, там нормально сортируется ключевое слово по алфавиту, а вот с дешифровкой возникли проблемы, не получается снова получить ключевое слово. Как быть с дешифровкой? Проблемную часть выделил "======". В самом конце

```pascal
var IT,KL,KL1:string;
tabl:array[1..10,1..10] of char;
vt,i,j,k:byte;
dkl:integer;
x,v:char;
begin
writeln('Введите E (encrypt) или D (decrypt) для выбора шифровки или расшифровки');
readln(v);
if v='E' then 
begin
writeln('Введите исходный текст, который надо зашифровать');
readln(IT);
for i:=1 to length(IT) do
if IT[i] in ['А'..'Я']then IT[i]:=chr(ord(IT[i])+32);
writeln('Исходный текст');
writeln(IT);
for i:=length(IT) downto 1 do
if IT[i]=' ' then delete(IT,i,1);
writeln('Введите ключ для шифровки');
readln(KL);
for i:=1 to length(KL) do
if KL[i] in ['А'..'Я']then KL[i]:=chr(ord(KL[i])+32);
dkl:=length(KL);
vt:=length(IT) div dkl;
writeln('Текст в исходной таблице для шифрования');
k:=0;
for i:=1 to vt do
 begin
  for j:=1 to dkl do
   begin
    inc(k);
    tabl[i,j]:=IT[k];
    write(tabl[i,j]:2);
   end;
  writeln;
 end;
for i:=1 to dkl-1 do
for j:=i+1 to dkl do
if kl[i]>kl[j] then
 begin
  x:=kl[i];
  kl[i]:=kl[j];
  kl[j]:=x;
  for k:=1 to vt do
   begin
    x:=tabl[k,i];
    tabl[k,i]:=tabl[k,j];
    tabl[k,j]:=x;
   end;
  end;
 writeln('Перестановка столбцов');
for i:=1 to vt do
 begin
  for j:=1 to dkl do
  write(tabl[i,j]:2);
  writeln;
 end;
IT:='';
for j:=1 to vt do
for i:=1 to dkl do
IT:=IT+tabl[j,i];
writeln('Криптограмма');
writeln(IT);
end;
if v='D' then 
begin

writeln('Введите исходный текст, который надо расшифровать');
readln(IT);
for i:=1 to length(IT) do
if IT[i] in ['А'..'Я']then IT[i]:=chr(ord(IT[i])+32);
writeln('Исходный текст');
writeln(IT);
for i:=length(IT) downto 1 do
if IT[i]=' ' then delete(IT,i,1);
writeln('Введите ключ для шифровки');
readln(KL);
for i:=1 to length(KL) do
if KL[i] in ['А'..'Я']then KL[i]:=chr(ord(KL[i])+32);
dkl:=length(KL);
vt:=length(IT) div dkl;
writeln('Текст в исходной таблице для расшифрования');
k:=0;
for i:=1 to vt do
 begin
  for j:=1 to dkl do
   begin
    inc(k);
    tabl[i,j]:=IT[k];
    write(tabl[i,j]:2);
   end;
  writeln;
 end;
 //=======================
for i:=1 to dkl-1 do
for j:=i+1 to dkl do
if kl1[i]=kl[j] then
 begin
  kl[i]:=kl1[j];
  for k:=1 to vt do
   begin
    x:=tabl[k,i];
    tabl[k,i]:=tabl[k,j];
    tabl[k,j]:=x;
   end;
  end;
 //=========================
 writeln('Перестановка столбцов');
for i:=1 to vt do
 begin
  for j:=1 to dkl do
  write(tabl[i,j]:2);
  writeln;
 end;
IT:='';
for j:=1 to vt do
for i:=1 to dkl do
IT:=IT+tabl[j,i];
writeln('Криптограмма');
writeln(IT);


end;
end.
```

Comment: алгоритм шифрования лучше бы описал

Comment: Есть ключевое слово, оно записывается в таблицу и под ним пишется наш текст, сортируем буквы ключевого слова по алфавиту и перемещаем столбцы, выписывает строки. http://imgur.com/a/6kT0IV7

Comment: @slippyk Вот текст шифрования "ТНПВЕ ГЛЕАР АДОНР ТИЕЬВ ОМОБТ МПЧИР 
ЫСООЬ" и он меняет столбцы и получается как на картинке выше

Comment: зашифрованный текст как будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил свой вопрос. Вот рабочий код на Паскале:

```
var IT,KL,KL1:string;
tabl:array[1..10,1..10] of char;
vt,i,j,k:byte;
dkl:integer;
x,v:char;
begin
writeln('Введите E (encrypt) или D (decrypt) для выбора шифровки или расшифровки');
readln(v);
if v='E' then 
begin
writeln('Введите исходный текст, который надо зашифровать');
readln(IT);
for i:=1 to length(IT) do
if IT[i] in ['А'..'Я']then IT[i]:=chr(ord(IT[i])+32);
writeln('Исходный текст');
writeln(IT);
for i:=length(IT) downto 1 do
if IT[i]=' ' then delete(IT,i,1);
writeln('Введите ключ для шифровки');
readln(KL);
for i:=1 to length(KL) do
if KL[i] in ['А'..'Я']then KL[i]:=chr(ord(KL[i])+32);
dkl:=length(KL);
vt:=length(IT) div dkl;
writeln('Текст в исходной таблице для шифрования');
k:=0;
for i:=1 to vt do
 begin
  for j:=1 to dkl do
   begin
    inc(k);
    tabl[i,j]:=IT[k];
    write(tabl[i,j]:2);
   end;
  writeln;
 end;
for i:=1 to dkl-1 do
for j:=i+1 to dkl do
if kl[i]>kl[j] then
 begin
  x:=kl[i];
  kl[i]:=kl[j];
  kl[j]:=x;
  for k:=1 to vt do
   begin
    x:=tabl[k,i];
    tabl[k,i]:=tabl[k,j];
    tabl[k,j]:=x;
   end;
  end;
 writeln('Перестановка столбцов');
for i:=1 to vt do
 begin
  for j:=1 to dkl do
  write(tabl[i,j]:2);
  writeln;
 end;
IT:='';
for j:=1 to vt do
for i:=1 to dkl do
IT:=IT+tabl[j,i];
writeln('Криптограмма');
writeln(IT);
end;
if v='D' then 
begin

writeln('Введите исходный текст, который надо расшифровать');
readln(IT);
for i:=1 to length(IT) do
if IT[i] in ['А'..'Я']then IT[i]:=chr(ord(IT[i])+32);
writeln('Исходный текст');
writeln(IT);
for i:=length(IT) downto 1 do
if IT[i]=' ' then delete(IT,i,1);
writeln('Введите ключ для шифровки');
readln(KL);
KL1:=KL;
for i:=1 to length(KL) do
if KL[i] in ['А'..'Я']then KL[i]:=chr(ord(KL[i])+32);
dkl:=length(KL);
vt:=length(IT) div dkl;
writeln('Текст в исходной таблице для расшифрования');
k:=0;
for i:=1 to vt do
 begin
  for j:=1 to dkl do
   begin
    inc(k);
    tabl[i,j]:=IT[k];
    write(tabl[i,j]:2);
   end;
  writeln;
 end;
for i:=1 to dkl-1 do
for j:=i+1 to dkl do
if kl[i]>kl[j] then
 begin
  x:=kl[i];
  kl[i]:=kl[j];
  kl[j]:=x;
end;
for i:=1 to dkl do
for j:=1 to dkl do
if kl1[i]=kl[j] then
 begin
  x:=kl[i];
  kl[i]:=kl[j];
  kl[j]:=x;
  for k:=1 to vt do
   begin
    x:=tabl[k,i];
    tabl[k,i]:=tabl[k,j];
    tabl[k,j]:=x;
   end;
  end;
 writeln('Перестановка столбцов');
for i:=1 to vt do
 begin
  for j:=1 to dkl do
  write(tabl[i,j]:2);
  writeln;
 end;
IT:='';
for j:=1 to vt do
for i:=1 to dkl do
IT:=IT+tabl[j,i];
writeln('Криптограмма');
writeln(IT);
end;
end.
```

Вот еще и рабочий код на Java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chiper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите 0 (encrypt) или 1 (decrypt) для выбора шифровки или расшифровки");
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1)
            decrypt();
        else encrypt();
        scanner.close();
    }

    private static void decrypt() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите исходный текст, который надо зашифровать");
        String sourceText = scanner.nextLine();
        sourceText = sourceText.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        System.out.println("Введите ключ для шифровки");
        String decryptionKey = scanner.nextLine();
        decryptionKey = decryptionKey.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        System.out.println("Текст в исходной таблице для шифрования");
        int count = 0;
        int highOfTable = sourceText.length() / decryptionKey.length();
        int lengthOfTable = decryptionKey.length();
        char[][] table = new char[10][10];

        char[] sourceTextChar = sourceText.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < highOfTable; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lengthOfTable; j++) {
                table[i][j] = sourceTextChar[count];
                System.out.print(table[i][j]);
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        char buffer;

        char[] decryptionKeyChar = decryptionKey.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfTable - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < lengthOfTable; j++) {
                if (decryptionKeyChar[i] > decryptionKeyChar[j]) {
                    buffer = decryptionKeyChar[i];
                    decryptionKeyChar[i] = decryptionKeyChar[j];
                    decryptionKeyChar[j] = buffer;

                    for (int k = 0; k < highOfTable; k++) {
                        buffer = table[k][i];
                        table[k][i] = table[k][j];
                        table[k][j] = buffer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Перестановка столбцов");
        for (int i = 0; i < highOfTable; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lengthOfTable; j++) {
                System.out.print(table[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        sourceText = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < highOfTable; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfTable; i++) {
                sourceText += Character.toString(table[j][i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Криптограмма\n" + sourceText);
    }

    private static void encrypt() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите исходный текст, который надо расшифровать");
        String sourceText = scanner.nextLine();
        sourceText = sourceText.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        System.out.println("Введите ключ для расшифровки");
        String decryptionKey = scanner.nextLine();
        decryptionKey = decryptionKey.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        String decryptionKey1 = decryptionKey;
        System.out.println("Текст в исходной таблице для шифрования");
        int count = 0;
        int highOfTable = sourceText.length() / decryptionKey.length();
        int lengthOfTable = decryptionKey.length();
        char[][] table = new char[10][10];

        char[] sourceTextChar = sourceText.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < highOfTable; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lengthOfTable; j++) {
                table[i][j] = sourceTextChar[count];
                System.out.print(table[i][j]);
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        char buffer;

        char[] decryptionKey1Char = decryptionKey1.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfTable - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < lengthOfTable; j++) {
                if (decryptionKey1Char[i] > decryptionKey1Char[j]) {
                    buffer = decryptionKey1Char[i];
                    decryptionKey1Char[i] = decryptionKey1Char[j];
                    decryptionKey1Char[j] = buffer;
                }
            }
        }

        char[] decryptionKeyChar = decryptionKey.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfTable - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < lengthOfTable; j++) {
                if (decryptionKeyChar[i] == decryptionKey1Char[j]) {
                    buffer = decryptionKey1Char[i];
                    decryptionKey1Char[i] = decryptionKey1Char[j];
                    decryptionKey1Char[j] = buffer;

                    for (int k = 0; k < highOfTable; k++) {
                        buffer = table[k][i];
                        table[k][i] = table[k][j];
                        table[k][j] = buffer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Перестановка столбцов");
        for (int i = 0; i < highOfTable; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lengthOfTable; j++) {
                System.out.print(table[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        sourceText = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < highOfTable; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfTable; i++) {
                sourceText += Character.toString(table[j][i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Криптограмма\n" + sourceText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не работает код, после запуска выдает вот что: [![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZw16.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZw16.png) После копирования кода на паскале, выдает то, что видно на изображении, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось как-то так:

```
program cipher;
const
  KEY = 'ПЕЛИКАН';
  MSG = 'ТЕРМИНАТОР ПРИБЫВАЕТ СЕДЬМОГО В ПОЛНОЧЬ';

type
  TIndexArray = array of integer; 

function BubbleSort(text: string): TIndexArray;
var
  i, j, n: integer;
  count: integer;
  tmp_c: char;
  tmp_i: integer;
begin
  n := Length(text);

  SetLength(result, n);
  For i := 1 to n do
    result[i - 1] := i - 1;

  For j := 1 to n - 1 do begin
    count := 0;
    For i := 1 to n - j do begin
      if (text[i] > text[i + 1]) then begin
        tmp_c := text[i];
        text[i] := text[i + 1];
        text[i + 1] := tmp_c;

        tmp_i := result[i - 1];
        result[i - 1] := result[i];
        result[i] := tmp_i;

        Inc(count);
      end;
    end;
    if (count = 0) then break;
  end;
end;

function IntArrayToStr(int_array: TIndexArray): string;
var
  s: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  result := '';
  For i := 0 to Length(int_array) - 1 do begin
    Str(int_array[i], s);
    result := result + s;
  end;
end;

function Encrypt(keyword, message: string): string;
var
  index: integer;
  row, rows: integer;
  index_array: TIndexArray;
  position: integer;
begin
  index := Pos(' ', message);
  While (index > 0) do begin
    Delete(message, index, 1);
    index := Pos(' ', message);
  end;

  rows := Length(message) Div Length(keyword);
  if (Length(message) Mod Length(keyword) <> 0) then
    Inc(rows);

  index_array := BubbleSort(keyword);
  result := '';

  For row := 1 to rows do begin
    For index := 0 to Length(index_array) - 1 do begin
      position := index_array[index] * rows + row;
      if (position > Length(message)) then
        continue;
      result := result + message[position];
    end;
  end;
end;

function Decrypt(keyword, cipher: string): string;
var
  index: integer;
  row, rows: integer;
  index_array: TIndexArray;
  position: integer;
begin
  rows := Length(cipher) Div Length(keyword);
  if (Length(cipher) Mod Length(keyword) <> 0) then
    Inc(rows);

  index_array := BubbleSort(keyword);
  index_array := BubbleSort(IntArrayToStr(index_array));
  result := '';

  For index := 0 to Length(index_array) - 1 do begin
    For row := 0 to rows - 1 do begin
      position := (index_array[index] + 1) + Length(keyword) * row;
      if (position > Length(cipher)) then
        continue;
      result := result + cipher[position];
    end;
  end;
end;

var
  enc, dec: string;
begin
  WriteLn(KEY, ' / ', MSG);
  WriteLn;
  enc := Encrypt(KEY, MSG);
  WriteLn('ENC: ', enc);
  dec := Decrypt(KEY, enc);
  WriteLn('DEC: ', dec);
end.
```

Вывод:

```
ПЕЛИКАН / ТЕРМИНАТОР ПРИБЫВАЕТ СЕДЬМОГО В ПОЛНОЧЬ

ENC: ГНВЕПЛТОААДРНЕВТЕЬИОРПОТМБЧМОРСОЫЬИ
DEC: ТЕРМИНАТОРПРИБЫВАЕТСЕДЬМОГОВПОЛНОЧЬ
```

Comment: Что то не то...  Текст записывается в строку. Т.е. самая верхняя строка, вторая строка и далее - "ТНПВЕ ГЛЕАР АДОНР ТИЕЬВ ОМОБТ МПЧИР ЫСООЬ" (Это он зашифрован другим способом) - потом переставляются столбцы и получается вот так "ГНВЕПЛТОААДРНЕВТЕЬИОРПОТМБЧМОРСОЫЬИ"

Comment: `ENC: ГНВЕПЛТОААДРНЕВТЕЬИОРПОТМБЧМОРСОЫЬИ` - это и получилось при шифровании, что не так?

Comment: он должен "ТНПВЕ ГЛЕАР АДОНР ТИЕЬВ ОМОБТ МПЧИР ЫСООЬ" превратить в "ГНВЕПЛТОААДРНЕВТЕЬИОРПОТМБЧМОРСОЫЬИ" Оно не работает так. Он получает на вход текст - записывает его в таблицу по-строчно. Затем используя ключевое слово переставляет столбцы местами, и в конце концов выписывает также строкой